# node js knex update record in a table

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to update a record in a tokens table with `knex` update.
I'm getting an exception when trying to update

code:

```js
async function updateUserToken(changeBody) {
  var result = await knex('tokens').where({ user_id: changeBody.user_id }).update({
    auth_token: changeBody.auth_token,
  });
  console.log(result);
}
```

the exception is:

```
Error: update  set `auth_token` = 'qwer' where `user_id` = 1 - SQLITE_ERROR: near "set": syntax error
```

migration file:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('users',  table  => {
        table.increments()
        table.string('email').primary
        table.string('name')
        table.string('password')
        table.timestamps();
    })
    .createTable('tokens',table => {
        table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users').onDelete('CASCADE')
        table.string('auth_token')
    })
    .createTable('address', function (table) {
        table.increments()
        table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users').onDelete('CASCADE')
        table.string('address_name').primary
        table.string('address_description')
        table.float('latitude')
        table.float('longitude')
    })
    .createTable('phones', function (table) {
        table.increments()
        table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users').onDelete('CASCADE')
        table.string('phone_number').primary
    })
    .createTable('items', function (table) {
        table.increments()
        table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users').onDelete('CASCADE')
        table.string('item_name')
        table.string('item_description')
        table.string('item_image_url')
    })
    .createTable('borrow_list', function (table) {
        table.increments()
        table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users').onDelete('CASCADE')
        table.integer('item_id').references('id').inTable('items')
        table.int('item_owner_user_id')
        table.string('item_borrower_user_id')
        table.string('deal_state')
    })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists("users").dropTableIfExists("address").
                dropTableIfExists("phones").dropTableIfExists("items")
};
```

Comment: Are you sure `tokens` table exist or it is spelled correctly?

Comment: @ Hassan Imam i added the migration file

Comment: Can you verify if you can see the `tokens` table in database?

Comment: yes i can, i saw it and the record i was trying to change

Comment: Which database are you using? From the error message, it is evident that table name doesn't exist.

Comment: the db im using is sqlite3

Comment: Are you able to select using knex ? Can you share the query?

Comment: async function test(user_id) {
    return (await db('tokens').where({user_id})) 
}, the query return a result

Comment: @Hassan Imam  never mind i found my error, i used a wrong variable, thank you very much for your help